Is there a ready-made function or solution to check initData for tg mini app in C#?
I'm trying to check the initData for a telegram mini app. Is there a ready-made function or solution for this in C#?
The problem occurs when there is a / in initData. For example in nickname or photoURL. Then the hash of my algorithm does not match.
Maybe I need to escape something in CheckString?
 var secretKey = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("WebAppData")).ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Program.tgToken));
 using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKey))
 {
     var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(checkString));
     var computedHashHex = BitConverter.ToString(computedHash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
     if (computedHashHex == tid.initData.hash)
         return tid;
 }


Don't know the details of the telegram hash. But hashing the secretkey seems weird. The HMAC standard does those things with long secrets to get a short secret key but that is something happening in the constructor of the HMACSHA256 class to fulfill the standards requirements. Its not something you have todo yourself before.

Ok. Seen it in the docs seems to be that is weeird but correct. https://core.telegram.org/bots/webapps#validating-data-received-via-the-mini-app
